# Is it Possible for data to flow thusly?: Infopath form to Access database to Sharepoint list

Tags: infopath, form, database, access

We have a department that could solve their issue with a post-it. Instead, they would like a form where people could enter data, and the data would pass to an Access DB, which would be tied a SP 2010 list where people could view/sort the data as desired. Any advice for using this sort of a workflow? Would it be better to skip the Access DB and just go 
Infopath->Sharepoint? Ideally new entries would be pushed all the way to the SP list in real time. This form will be used maybe a few times a year and contain minimal data, 3 or 4 fields, hence the sarcasm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well best would be to avoid the Access DB layer, SharePoint -> List is the best way..

But if its necessary, you can write a Custom WCF Service, call this service from InfoPath form.. And use C# to add contents to Access Database.. You can use **Business Connectivity Services: External Lists** to connect to Access Database and show the List View.

Let me know if you need instructions..